# Proving A and Not A are Dependent Events

Tags: probability

How do I prove that an event and its complement are dependent on each other? Clearly both outcomes cannot happen, but I don't know how to formally prove it.

Comment: Not quite always. Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$. This automatically holds if $\Pr(A)=0$ or $\Pr(B)=0$.

Comment: I know this, but what I asked is how to show an event and its complement are dependent.

Comment: I showed that an event $A$ and its complement **can** be independent. Also showed that **if** $\Pr(A)$ is different from $0$ or $1$, then $A$ and its complement are not independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite always. Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$. This automatically holds if $\Pr(A)=0$ or $\Pr(B)=0$.

Suppose now that $B$ is the complement of $A$. Let $p=\Pr(A)$. Then if $p=0$, or $p=1$, then $A$ and $B$ **are** independent. We show that this is the only situation in which $A$ and its complement $B$ can be independent.

For if $B$ is the complement of $A$, then $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$.  Thus if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $p(1-p)=0$. This forces $p=0$ or $p=1$.

Comment: If they're complements, isn't the union 1?

Comment: If they are complements, then the union has probability $1$. But we are working with intersection, which is the empty set, so has probability $0$. Thanks, I had a typo!

Answer (score 1):

$$A\cap A^c = \emptyset$$

Therefore

$$\Pr(A\cap A^c) = 0$$

But if $A$ and $A^c$ are independent, then $\Pr(A\cap A^c) = \Pr(A)\Pr(A^c)$.

Therefore, either $\Pr(A)=0$ or $\Pr(A^c)=0$.